# Setting up subreport in iReport using XML datasource

Tags: xml, ireport, subreport

Can anyone explain in details (if possible, with screenshots) how to add a subreport (one to many relation)

This being the xml data source

```
<addressbook>
 <category name="home">
  <person id="1">                                                           
      <LASTNAME>Davolio</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Nancy</FIRSTNAME>
      <hobbies>
       <hobby>Radio Control</hobby>
       <hobby>R/C Cars</hobby>
       <hobby>Micro R/C Cars</hobby>
       <hobby>Die-Cast Models</hobby>
      </hobbies>
      <email>email1@my.domain.it</email>
      <email>email2@my.domain2.it</email> 

  </person>
  <person id="2">
      <LASTNAME>Fuller</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Andrew</FIRSTNAME>
      <email>email3@my.domain3.it</email> 
      <email>email4@my.domain4.it</email> 
  </person>
  <person id="3">                                                                 
      <LASTNAME>Leverling</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Janet</FIRSTNAME>
      <hobbies>
       <hobby>Rockets</hobby>
       <hobby>Puzzles</hobby>
       <hobby>Science Hobby</hobby>
       <hobby>Toy Horse</hobby> 
      </hobbies>
      <email>email45@my.domain3.it</email> 
      <email>email455@my.domain4.it</email> 
  </person>
 </category>
 <category name="work">    
  <person id="4">                                                            
      <LASTNAME>Peacock</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Margaret</FIRSTNAME>
      <hobbies>
       <hobby>Toy Horse</hobby> 
      </hobbies>
      <email>Peacock@margaret.com</email>  
  </person>
  <person id="5">
      <LASTNAME>Buchanan</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Steven</FIRSTNAME>
      <hobbies>
      </hobbies>
      <email>Buchanan@steven.com</email>  
  </person>
  <person id="6">
      <LASTNAME>Suyama</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Michael</FIRSTNAME>
  </person>
  <person id="7">
      <LASTNAME>King</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Robert</FIRSTNAME>
  </person>
 </category>
 <category name="Other">    
  <person id="8">   
      <LASTNAME>Callahan</LASTNAME>
      <FIRSTNAME>Laura</FIRSTNAME>
      <email>email25@my.domain3.it</email> 
  </person>
  <person id="9">
      <LASTNAME>Dodsworth</LASTNAME>
      <email>Dodsworth@my.anne.it</email> 
  </person>
 </category>                                                           
</addressbook>
```

Comment: You did not specify what technology you are using for reporting. There is no way for people to answer your question.

Comment: Actually, he did specify the technology. It's "iReport" (a Jasper reporting GUI). He could've tagged with "ireport" and "jasper-reporting" though.

Answer (score 0):

This page here has exactly what you need:

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=48534

Basically some guy was trying to do exactly what you're doing (with the same page and everything) and had the same problem. Awesomely enough, he pasted in his XML datasource and his master and subreport JRXML files. View his code to see how he did it, then use the <datasourceExpression> syntax the second comment suggests to get things going.